# Slide a View Horizontally & Hide its Content

Tags: android, view, slide

I wanted to create a View that could slide Horizontally on user touch only & get Hide it's content when it touches any other View ...

Here is the What I am trying to do...

```
 [my second view] A B C D E F G [my first view]
```

on Sliding Horizontally...

```
 [my second view] C D E F G [my first view]
```

Any Answer Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should customize this as you wanted, atleast you must try that. So that any one here can help you when you are stuck. Try the following Links

[Horizontal listview](http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/)

[Source code horizontal listview](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

As you told the below 2 links may help you out

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943

Comment: thks for answer...I have tried Horizontal ScrollView but since I have only one TextView which I want to scroll...for example what we see in the Sliding lock of android phones ======swipe===to Unlock

Comment: If you want such a control its simple, can you explain your exact need

Comment: you should setOntouchListener for the edittext , Wait i will get you some help

Answer (score 0):

If your content is button or text then you can use Horizontal ScrollView and if you want to slide images then go for Gallery.

You can asl if you have any further queries.

Comment: I have tried Horizontal ScrollView and Gallery is Deprecated...I have a Single TextView which I want to move as I have shown in my small Diagram

Comment: any other suggestion could be useful thks